# What is the maximum length of a comment in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, metadata, comments

PostgreSQL has a special piece of a functionality called [`COMMENT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html) which attaches metadata to an identifier or any type (schema, table, column, function, type, domain, etc). It looks like this,

```
COMMENT ON TABLE mytable IS 'This is my table.';
```

Is there a maximum size for the comment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`COMMENT` has no impositions other than it fit into a `TEXT` field (verified in IRC with RhodiumToad),

From [the docs,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)

> Very long values are also stored in background tables so that they do not interfere with rapid access to shorter column values. In any case, **the longest possible character string that can be stored is about 1 GB.**

So if you're under a GB or thereabout, you're probably fine.

Comment: The real question is: "Will that be enough?" ;-)